# Show Data of related object in Template - Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, foreign-keys

In a template, I want to show the data of all objects related to the "source-object".

This is the model of the Events that I want to show on the Article detail page:

```
### Models ###
class EventRecord(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='events')
    event_date = models.DateField('Event Date')
    country = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    location = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    actors = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    .
    .
    .
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.event_date
```

This is the view I wrote for it (this works):

```
### View ###
def article_detail(request, pk):
    """ Detail View for articles"""
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)
    events = article.events.all()

    return render(request, 'coding/article-detail.html', {'article': article,
    'events': events})
    pass
```

This template works too, but all I see is the event_date info.

```
### Template ### 
<div>
<h2>Events</h2>
{% for event in events %}
    {{ event }}
{% endfor %}

</div>
```

Is this because of`__unicode__(self)`?
What do I have to do to see **all** the event info?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, when rendering `{{event}}` you are just seeing it's representation, which you defined in the method `__unicode__` as the event_date field. If you want to see other fields of EventRecord just render them like this:

```
{% for event in events %}
    {{ event.country }}
    {{ event.location }}
    .
    .
    .
{% endfor %}
```